# 'hiveserver2 not listening on port 10000 and 10001'

Tags: hive

When I run:

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

It shows

> Starting HiveServer2

and nothing listens on port 10000 and 10001

Answer (score 4):

The `HiveServer2` service does not output error information, causing it hard to diagnostic the problem. You can try to start the `metastore` service provided by Hive, which listens on port 9083 and might give some information when your configuration is not properly set:

```sh
 hive --service metastore    # not detach from terminal to see logs
```

In my case, this service cannot be started, with error message:

```
MetaException(message:Hive Schema version 3.1.0 does not match metastore's schema 
version 1.2.0 Metastoed or corrupt)
```

[One of the direct solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47523575/messagehive-schema-version-1-2-0-does-not-match-metastores-schema-version-2-1) to resolve this error is to ignore the version difference by setting the `hive-site.xml` if there is only one hive version in your machine (another solution is to [modify the `metastore_db` version](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_27882063/article/details/79886935)):

```xml
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.schema.verification</name>
    <value>false</value>
</property>
```

After this problem is resolved, the `HiveServer2` service can be running and listening on port 10000.

```sh
hive --service hiveserver2 > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

> If your `HiveServer2` access `metastore` via `Derby` or `MySQL` JDBC driver, then the aforementioned `metastore` service is not needed for `HiveServer2`. However, if `HiveServer2` access `metastore` via `thrift` protocol, as configed in `conf/hive-site.xml` like
>
> ```xml
> <property>
>    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
>    <value>thrift://hadoop-master:9083</value>
>    <description>
>      Thrift URI for the remote metastore.
>      Used by metastore client to connect to remote metastore.
>    </description>
>  </property>
> ```
>
> Then, the `metastore` service must be started at first.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time to set up `hive-3.1.2`. I write this maybe it helps someone out. in order to diagnose the problem first try to launch `metastore` and `hiveserver2` like this:

metastore:

```
hive --service metastore --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

hiveserver2:

```
hive --service hiveserver2 --hiveconf hive.server2.thrift.port=10000 --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console
```

then carefully read the the exceptions were thrown.

my problem was `user hive is not allowed to perform this api call`
and to solve that I added the following property to `hive-site.xml`:

```xml
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.event.db.notification.api.auth</name>
  <value>false</value>
  <description>
    Should metastore do authorization against database notification related APIs such as get_next_notification.
    If set to true, then only the superusers in proxy settings have the permission
  </description>
</property>
```

also I add my full `hive-site.xml` as a sample:

```
<configuration> 
<property> 
    <name>datanucleus.schema.autoCreateTables</name> 
    <value>true</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
    <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name> 
    <value>jdbc:mysql://server-2:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value> 
</property> 

<property>  
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>   
     <value>mysql_username</value>   
</property> 

<property> 
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name> 
     <value>mysql_password</value>
</property> 

<property> 
     <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name> 
     <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>    
    <value>thrift://server-2:9083</value> 
</property> 
    
<property> 
    <name>atanucleus.fixedDatastore</name> 
    <value>true</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
     <name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name> 
     <value>server-2</value>
</property> 

<property> 
     <name>hive.server2.transport.mode</name> 
     <value>binary</value> 
</property> 

<property> 
     <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name> 
     <value>false</value>  
</property> 
 
<property> 
     <name>hive.metastore.event.db.notification.api.auth</name> 
     <value>false</value> 
</property> 
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. There is typo. It should hive.metastore not as shown below.

**metastore**.metastore.event.db.notification.api.auth 
    false